# How to highlight a bound field's item?

Tags: css, asp.net, gridview

This is my asp code:-

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        Width="245px" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="users" HeaderText="Chat Users" ReadOnly="True">
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="Black" 
                HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="chatUsers" />
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
```

and here's my css:-

```
    <style>
.chatUsers
{
    cursor:pointer;

}
</style>
```

I tried adding background-color property to the css but it doesn't work. how to change the background color of the item on mouse over?

Comment: Why do you play with asp.net without mastering basics of html and css first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:BoundField ItemStyle-CssClass="item_style" DataField="blah" />
```